# Load Content From Other PHP files in Main Page With Ajax Using onClick

Tags: jquery

I want to submit search term to search page from index page we out refresh the whole index page with the following HTML form and AJAX code but it seems AJAX is sending empty values to search_m.php and not able to display the results in the  on index page can one point me where am doing it wrong am not good in AJAX ?
Note am searching in database

Thanks and regards

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery9min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$('#search_btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "search_m.php",
    data : $('#search_toggle').val(),
    success: function (html) {
      $("#more-info").html(html);
    }
});
</script>

<form style="width:230px; margin:0 auto;" id="find" method="GET">
<input type="image" src="images/searchthis.png" id="search_btn">
<input type="text" id="search_toggle" name="q" placeHolder="type to start searching">
</form>


<div id="more-info">content should be displayed here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not specifying the key, only the value of the data you are trying to pass. data can take an object or serialized data
Try passing

```
 data:{q:$('#search_toggle').val()}
 //or
 url:"Searchm.php?q="+$('#search_toggle').val()
```

On a sidenote, you can use load

```
$("#more-info").load("search_m.php?q="+$('#search_toggle').val());
```

This will simply paste the data in #more-info field. If it doesn't work, check the js console for errors. It might give u a hint